# JQuery rating plugin doesn't work on KO loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, jquery-bar-rating

I have tried using two bar rating plugins, one of them found [here](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating): the other, [here](http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/). Using the first listed rating plugin, when I mouse over the stars, they don't work at all (meaning the color of the selected stars don't change) while in the KnockoutJS loop, if outside, it works perfectly fine. Sample code:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: articles">    
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="1" class="star" />
        <input type="radio" name="1" class="star" />
        <input type="radio" name="1" class="star" />
        <input type="radio" name="1" class="star" />
        <input type="radio" name="1" class="star" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){ // wait for document to load
                $('input.star').rating();
            });                 
        </script>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- Works -->
```

My CSS is setup and I even tried moving the plugin activation script inside/outside the loop and nothing.

**EDIT**
I guess the question would be, how could I re-apply the plugin to KnockoutJS after the new content is generated?

Comment: your loop executes after jQuery ready...so 1st part of your script already triggered and that was all folks.... you need to move your js after the loop cause you do same thing to each iteration...

Comment: Your problem is probably because you are selecting all `input` with the class `star`, which, after the last loop of the `foreach` is *all* of the inputs added in the loop. You need to limit it to just the one for each article. The way to do that would be to probably select the `li`s and then for each one select the group of radio buttons under it and call `rating` on them.

Comment: @HellBaby I tried moving the js to several parts of the document, inside and outside the loop, outside `li` etc. Same thing.

Comment: @MattBurland I tried the following: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ // wait for document to load
 $('.li').each(function(){
  $(this).find('input.star').rating();
 });
});     
</script> ` and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the plugin is running before the elements are rendered on the page by KnockoutJS. The way to fix this, as I found, is by checking when the elements are set and then re-attaching the plugin.

This should be added to the loop.

```
foreach: { data: articles, afterRender: rating_bind } //rating_bind is the function that will map the plugin to the new elements.
```